# Oracle random date and time

Tags: oracle, datetime

I am using the code below to generate random dates, which works fine.

Can this be modified to add a random time to the date between from 00:00:00 - 23:59:59

My attempt below failed and I'm unsure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';


SELECT TO_DATE(
              TRUNC(
                   DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2021-01-01','J')
                                    ,TO_CHAR(DATE '2022-12-31','J')
                                    )
                    ),'J' +
NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,86399)), 'SECOND')
               ) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have brackets in the wrong place:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(
         TRUNC(
           DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(
             TO_CHAR(DATE '2021-01-01','J'),
             TO_CHAR(DATE '2022-12-31','J')
           )
         ),
         'J'
       )
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL(
           FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,86399)),
           'SECOND'
         )
FROM   DUAL;
```

*Note: it helps if you format your code so that indentation matches the brackets and then you can more easily spot errors like this.*

You can simplify the code to:

```sql
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01'
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL(
           DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, DATE '2022-12-31' - DATE '2021-01-01' + 1),
           'DAY'
         )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Or, even simpler:

```sql
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01'
       + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, DATE '2022-12-31' - DATE '2021-01-01' + 1)
FROM   DUAL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9341323230ba1d54743cedcc69858743)*

Comment: MTO thanks for your help, patience and expertise. I have 2 questions if you don't mind? First, what's the purpose of the +1? Second, can this method be used to randomly populate the fractional part ONLY of a timestamp( upto 6 digits) too without Incrementing the seconds?

Comment: @Pugzly If you consider when the start day is the same as the end day then the difference is zero days but you still want to generate random times for that 24 hour period so you need to add 1 to get that extra period. If you do not add 1 then you will get random values from the start date to less than the end date.

Comment: @Pugzly Yes, you can set the fractional seconds of a timestamp [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e1116a33a0f770ef8eab70599da56cec).

Comment: MTO perfect!!! thanks for the eloquent and more condensed solution.